# What's the difference between if( !(s & i) ) and if( s&i == 0 )?

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

eg.

```
int main(){
    int s = 4, i = 3;
    if(s & i == 0)   cout << (s & i) << endl;
    if(!(s & i))    cout << (s & i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output only one zero.
Why not no print or print two zero?

Comment: Thank a lot, i get it. I may forgot the operator priority.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`==` has higher precedence than `&`. So

```
if (s & i == 0)
```

is actually equivalent to

```
if (s & (i == 0))
```

In other words, you're checking if `i` is `0` and then `&`ing the result (0 or 1) with `s`. You probably wanted

```
if ((s & i) == 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

The first condition

```
if(s & i == 0)   cout << (s & i) << endl;
```

is equivalent to this condition

```
if(s & ( i == 0 ) )   cout << (s & i) << endl;
```

and has nothing common with this condition

```
if(!(s & i))    cout << (s & i) << endl;
```

I think you mean

```
if( ( s & i ) == 0)   cout << (s & i) << endl;
```

In this case the both conditions are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

The equality comparison operator (`==`) has a higher precedence than the bitwise and operator (`&`), so the first expression is equivalent to:

```
if(s & (i == 0))   cout << (s & i) << endl;
```

Since `i` is set to `3`, `(i == 0)` is `false`, which is converted to `0` when bitwise and'ed.  `4 & 0` equals `0`, so nothing is printed.